# AWS CloudFront failover

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have the following business continuity (BC) solution:

1. Static website that is deployed in S3 in two identical buckets in regions A (primary) and B (secondary).
2. CloudFront distribution that uses Origin Group to failover from the bucket in region A to the other one in region B.
3. The distribution is configured with the custom domain and certificates to provide access to the website.
4. Route 53 has "A" record connecting the custom domain to the CloudFront distribution.

The above solution works as indented, i.e. it provides the failover in case of the failure of the primary site (e.g. S3 failure).

What I am trying to figure out is the best way to ensure the availability of the CloudFront distribution, i.e. what happens if the region where the distribution is configured becomes compromised.

Originally I was thinking to create another distribution that will be identical to the first one but will exist in another region and use Route 53 to failover between them. Unfortunately it is not possible due to the one-to-one relationship between a CF distribution and customer domains (CNAME).

I would appreciate anyone's experience with creating a BC solution for the CloudFront distribution that uses custom domains.

Thank you,
gen

Comment: Isn't part of the point of services like CloudFront to automatically failover to alternate infrastructure if there is a failure,  thus to try to engineer for this case is the same as simply creating your own CDN by routing between multiple services using e.g. haproxy, squid,  dns tricks etc?

Comment: I do not think you can really protect against CloudFront failures. Do the uptime guarantees not suffice for you?

Comment: @luk2302. Thank you for the comment. Uptime SLA states 99.9% monthly availability, but as we saw last week the key infrastructure components with the same SLA target (e.g. Cognito) were down for several hours.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Thank you for the comment. I am not sure I understand the internals of CloudFront architecture to assess its ability to overcome a failure of the region where the distribution is deployed.

Comment: To be honest: then you should start learning about the internals. If you are that worried about it and think you can do better then there is not much else to do other than REALLY understanding and getting to know the service and its limitations. How often has CloudFront been down in the last 5 years?